# Jquery .on('dblclick') event not firing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem where the 'dblclick' event fires just fine in chrome but in firefox seems to not work. This also happens with the 'click' event.

```js
$(document).on('dblclick','.NomeCategoria',function(event){  
  $(".NomeCategoria").each(function(){
         $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
     });
     $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="19" disabled="disabled" class="NomeCategoria" value="Banchetto">
```

I already searched around but i couldn't find anything.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Pointy for pointing out the other question.
I was able to resolve this problem by using 'readonly' instead of 'disabled'.

The 'disabled' style is not present but thats not a problem for me.

Comment: Do you have click event too to .NomeCategoria?

Comment: No, i have no other events bound to that class